# storing ssh remote executed command output to variable is blocking. connection not ending?

Tags: bash, ssh, openssh

I'm not quite sure what the issue is. I'm on Kali Linux 2.0 right now, fresh install. The following worked on Ubuntu 14.04 but it's not working anymore (maybe I accidentally changed it?). It looks correct to me, but every time it runs it blocks.

```
backup_folder=$(ssh -i /home/dexter/.ssh/id_rsa $server 'ls -t '$dir' | head -1')
```

This is part of a larger script. $server and $dir are set. When I run the command alone, I get the correct output, but it doesn't end the connection.

Comment: just FYI, it works for me on Ubuntu 15.04. I also don't see anything wrong on the first sight.

Comment: You may want to quote the `$dir` expansion, lest you might run into problems if `$dir` ever expands to a path that contains whitespace or shell metacharacters.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why the command would hang, but you don't need to run the whole pipeline on the server.  It's enough to do the `ls` there:

```
backup_folder=$( ssh -i keyfile "$server" "ls -t -- '$dir'" | head -n 1 )
```

Note that this quotes the `$dir` value on the remote side (it will still be expanded locally).  The `head` will run locally.

This also comes with the caveats mentioned in the answers to "[Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985)".

Comment: If `ls` generates a lot of output it will be more efficient to run the `head` on the remote side

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem and by consulting man ssh, I found out:

```
# Problem: if you copy & paste those two lines together into a shell, 
# then the second command is not executed. 
# But if you run each line on its own, it will work
srcdirs=$(ssh myserver "ls -1 /home")
echo "$srcdirs"   # command is also not recorded by history

# Solution: Redirect stdin from /dev/null
srcdirs=$(ssh -n myserver "ls -1 /home")
echo "$srcdirs"
```

Hope, this solves your issue...

Answer (score -1):

I have had the same issue recently, probably you should add a redirection to stdout at the end of the command, like so:

```
backup_folder=$(ssh -i /home/dexter/.ssh/id_rsa $server 'ls -t '$dir' | head -1' 2>&1)
```

Comment: That would cause error messages to be part of the `$backup_folder` string.